Skipping problem in block building system in Unity
I am new to Unity and I am trying to make a building system that is similar to Minecraft but in isometric view and you use a cursor to place the blocks. The code I have below are bit and pieces that I found here and in YouTube videos.
The problem that I am facing right now is that it works for the first few block places but skips a block after a few tries as shown. The white block is where the block is intended to be placed but after reaching the 3rd block, it skips up.
Sample run of block placing
The code below is what determines the mouse position. GetHitFace() is used to determine which face the the cursor is pointing to (whether the up, west, or south face of the block), and GetHitTag() is used to determine what object is being hit (whether the map plane or a block).
What I tried to do is determine what the cursor is pointing to using a ray cast. If it points to the map plane, the position the block is placed is in the cell it exactly points to (there is an existing grid system). If it points to a block, the face at which it is pointed to is determined and the mouse position is incremented/decremented based on this so that when I place a block, I don't place it inside the block, rather to the cell adjacent to it.
It works fine at first but skips a block as shown in the picture after a certain level or after a few blocks have been placed. I am pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this building system, any help would be appreciated for a beginner like me.
This is inside the input manager and what determines the cell in which the block highlight (white block that shows where the block is to be placed) is to be rendered.
public Vector3 GetSelectedMapPosition()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = sceneCamera.nearClipPlane;
    Ray ray = sceneCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
    RaycastHit hit;

    BlockFace activeHitFace = GetHitFace();
    string activeHitTag = GetHitTag();

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, layerMask) && activeHitTag == "Map Plane")
    {
        hit.point = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x / gridManager.UnityGridSize), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y / gridManager.UnityGridSize), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z / gridManager.UnityGridSize));
        return lastPosition = hit.point;
    }
    else if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, layerMask) && activeHitTag == "Block")
    {
        if (activeHitFace == BlockFace.Up)
        {
            hit.point = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x / gridManager.UnityGridSize), (Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y / gridManager.UnityGridSize)) + 1, Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z / gridManager.UnityGridSize));
            return lastPosition = hit.point;
        }
        else if (activeHitFace == BlockFace.West)
        {
            hit.point = new Vector3((Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x / gridManager.UnityGridSize)) - 1, (Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y / gridManager.UnityGridSize)), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z / gridManager.UnityGridSize));
            return lastPosition = hit.point;
        }
        if (activeHitFace == BlockFace.South)
        {
            hit.point = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x / gridManager.UnityGridSize), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y / gridManager.UnityGridSize), (Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z / gridManager.UnityGridSize)) - 1);
            return lastPosition = hit.point;
        }
        else if (activeHitFace == BlockFace.West)
        {
            hit.point = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x / gridManager.UnityGridSize) - 1, (Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y / gridManager.UnityGridSize)), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z / gridManager.UnityGridSize));
            return lastPosition = hit.point;
        }

    }

    return lastPosition;
}

This code here is for the build mode which is called by the Update(). "B" must be pressed to enter build mode wherein the block highlight shows and when the mouse is clicked. A block is instantiated where that block highlight is.
    void EnterBuildMode()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = inputManager.GetSelectedMapPosition();
        blockHighlight.transform.position = mousePosition;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log(inputManager.GetSelectedMapPosition());
            Debug.Log(inputManager.GetHitFace());
            Debug.Log(inputManager.GetHitTag());
            BuildBlock();
        }
    }
    void BuildBlock()
    {
        Vector3 spawnPosition = inputManager.GetSelectedMapPosition();
        Instantiate(block, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, Blocks);
    }


surely the problem is that the hitpoint is a block not the ground, and so the hint point would be the top surface, not, the location of the cube, therefore, you're skipping one, because the hint point is where the base of the next should be but you're adding 1
